# Add new column based on changes in text in another column

Tags: r

**MY DATA**

```
Fruits <- c("Orange","Orange","Pineapple","Pineapple","Orange","Orange","Blueberry")
Location <- c(10, 11, 15, 16, 10, 11, 30)
```

**MY PROBLEM**

I wish to add a new column, `Entry` that contains a different ID for when there is a change in `Fruit` from the row above.

**EXAMPLE OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE**

```
Fruits <- c("Orange","Orange","Pineapple","Pineapple","Orange","Orange","Blueberry")
Location <- c(10, 11, 15, 16, 10, 11, 30)
Entry <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
```

Note how the second entry of `"Orange"` receives a different ID to the first, even though it is added at the same `Location`. My thought is to write a loop that would iterate over `Fruits` for a change in text, placing a value in `Entry`. All values in `Entry` must be consecutive. This seems a simple exercise but I am stuck!
Thank you.

Comment: Please post a **[reproducible code snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)**. Use `dput()` and give us just a snippet of your dataframe.

Comment: Distribution just by fruit, or by fruit and location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical `rle` problem, in which you can get what you are looking for by expanding the `lengths` value from the result of `rle`:

```
> A <- rle(Fruits)
> rep(seq_along(A$lengths), A$lengths)
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4
```

Comment: Similarly, `cumsum` can do it - `cumsum(Fruits != c(".NOTHING.",head(Fruits,-1)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
table(df$Fruits)
```

is what you want to get the frequency distribution of the number of fruits within the dataset. If you want distribution by fruit and location, then tell us that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My dataset is 344156 obs. of 2 variables, the above is an abbreviated version for example purposes. I used fruits as my data contains confidential names. I wish to...
 a) Create a frequency distribution of the number of fruits within the dataset. Simply counting the occurence of different fruits (for example, the number of times orange appears) is misleading.
b) My main aim is to count the interaction between fruits... what fruit appears after another fruit at each location. Hence the need for the different ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using @thelatemail's advice and an answer from... [Creating a column in r that auto-increments based on other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539764/creating-a-column-in-r-that-auto-increments-based-on-other-columns?rq=1), I utilised the following code:

`indx <- as.character(interaction(Analysis[c(1)]))`
`Analysis$Entry <- cumsum(c(TRUE,indx[-1]!=indx[-length(indx)]))`

Where `Analysis` is my `data.frame` and `Fruits` is the first column.